# pca: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r

I tried to do the pca analysis of a matrix.

Thanks in advance for great help!

Best,

Yue

```
plot(pca)
{plot(pca$x[,1],pca$x[,2])
  points(pca$x[1:14,1],pca$x[1:14,2],col=2,pch=2)
  points(pca$x[16:31,1],pca$x[15:31,2],col=3,pch=2)
}
```

I tried:

```
> length(pca$x[,1])
[1] 31
> length(pca$x[,2])
[1] 31
> lines(pca$x[,1],pca$x[,2])

Plot is:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuA59.png
```

Comment: The second `points` call has `pca$x[16:31,1]` and `pca$x[15:31,2]` (different sizes)

Comment: Hello, Aziz,  Thank you so much for your great help!  Yue